# Adding elements to xml file in C# using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement, xattribute

this is my current XML structure

```
<root>
<sublist>
    <sub a="test" b="test" c="test"></sub>
  </sublist>
</root>
```

i use the following C# but get error when i try to excute

```
 public static void writeSub(string a,string b,string c)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(sourceFile);
            XElement root = new XElement("sub");
            root.Add(new XAttribute("a", a), new XAttribute("b", b),
                         new XAttribute("c", c));
            xDoc.Element("sub").Add(root);
            xDoc.Save(sourceFile);
        }
```

where do i get it wrong?

error is

```
nullreferenceexception was unhandled
```

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is null.

Comment: What do you think `xDoc.Element("sub")` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems because `sub` is not root element of document. So, when you do

```
xDoc.Element("sub").Add(root);
```

Then `xDoc.Element("sub")` returns `null`. Then when you try to call method `Add` you have `NullReferenceException`.

I think you need to add new `sub` element to `sublist` element:

```
xDoc.Root.Element("sublist").Add(root);
```

Also I suggest to improve naming. If you are creating element `sub`, then call varibale `sub` instead of naming it `root` (that is very confusing). E.g.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sourceFile);
var sub = new XElement("sub", 
               new XAttribute("a", a), 
               new XAttribute("b", b),
               new XAttribute("c", c));

xdoc.Root.Element("sublist").Add(sub);
xdoc.Save(sourceFile);
```

Comment: thx, it works but in the end i get <sub a="a" b="b" c="c" /> not <sub a="a" b="b" c="c"></sub>

Comment: There is no difference in these definitions. You can try to provide empty string as value of `sub` element to get required result (sorry, can't verify this suggestion here).